# I have to create same Jhipster yo.rc.json as in my old project

Tags: jhipster

I am working on rebuild the same jhipster application as previous one bcoz old project are having some problems.
The problem is that, project was created in version 2.1.27 and I have to create the same kind of project in 3.8.0. So, jhipster question and answer pattern is changed and I am confused what to answer to that question.

For Example : I had xauth authentication in my previous app. but while building new jhipster app I dont see any such kind of authentication there are three options: HTTP,OAUTH2 and JWT. what should I have to select. Further more I will share my old yo.rc.JSON can anybuddy guild me correct answer to build new jhipster yo.rc file

```
{
"generator-jhipster": {
"baseName": "myApp",
"packageName": "com.myApp.app",
"packageFolder": "com/myApp/app",
"authenticationType": "xauth",
"hibernateCache": "no",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "no",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "mysql",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": "no",
"useSass": false,
"buildTool": "maven",
"frontendBuilder": "grunt",
"javaVersion": "7",
"enableTranslation": false,
"rememberMeKey": "c1a3776920bbeb376eeecd42e91cccdeaoada010"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JWT authentication. This was changed in 3.0 https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/2f017636700790aa5b38554da71fc27801b67cd3

Regarding migration of your full yo-rc.json, you have to try by yourself by generating new projects.

Few hints:

```
"frontendBuilder": "grunt",  <-- we only support gulp now
"javaVersion": "7", <-- we only support java 8
"enableTranslation": false, <-- probably need to list languages
"rememberMeKey": "c1a3776920bbeb376eeecd42e91cccdeaoada010" <-- secret key maybe
```

Comment: and what about of other question ? can you please post ro.rc.json in 3.8 version according to given configs ?

Comment: Jhipster is Migrated from xauth to JWT in version 3.0. Thanks Gael Marziou.

Comment: I 'm available for prefessional consoluting if you want me to do your work ;)

Comment: sure How can we connect ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    {
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.8.0",
    "baseName": "myApp",
    "packageName": "com.myApp.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/myApp/app",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "JWT",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.8.0",
    "baseName": "myApp",
    "packageName": "com.myApp.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/myApp/app",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "JWT",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}